# Grabbing multiple screens

Tags: qt, qt5

I have a system with a dual (extended) screen and try to make screen copies of both:

```
QList<QScreen*> screenList = QGuiApplication::screens();
int i;

for (i = 0; i < screenList.size(); i++)
{
    QPixmap screencopy = screenList[i]->grabWindow(QApplication::desktop()->winId());
    ...
}
```

Although screenList contains pointers to two different screens the result when accessing screenList[0] and screenList[1] is always the same, it makes a screen copy of the first screen only.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Which OS/window manager are you using? That might affect the results.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld this is a surprising question as Qt should behave the same on all platforms!? Nevertheless, I'm currently trying with Windows 10 and extended screens.

Comment: That’s the theory, but the abstractions are not perfect, there still can be platform-specific bugs or different behavior, especially in non-core features that are only thin wrappers around the native platform.

Answer (score 2):

You can access screens via `QDesktopWidget`:

```
QDesktopWidget *widget = QApplication::desktop();
    int screens= widget->screenCount();
    QRect *screenRect=new QRect[screens];
    for (int i = 0; i < screens; ++i)
    {
         *(screenRect+i) = widget->screen(i)->geometry();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For the both screen (or second) use this:

```
QPixmap screencopy = screen->grabWindow(0, screen->geometry().x(), screen->geometry().y(), screen->size().width(), screen->size().height());
```

Comment: This does not work, then the second scree image is completely black.